# How to check status of Meta Strip toggle with python?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

In the VSE, if I select a [Meta Strip](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/meta.html), I can toggle its 'expanded view' with <kbd>Tab</kbd> or by calling the [`bpy.ops.sequencer.meta_toggle()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.sequencer.html?highlight=meta_toggle#bpy.ops.sequencer.meta_toggle) python operator.

How do I check whether or not a *Meta Strip* is currently in 'expanded' or 'collapsed view' via python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
seq_editor = scene.sequence_editor

if len(seq_editor.meta_stack) > 0:
    meta_name = seq_editor.meta_stack[-1].name
    print(meta_name + ' is currently expanded')
else:
    print('All meta strips are collapsed')
```

See [meta_stack](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.SequenceEditor.html?highlight=meta_stack#bpy.types.SequenceEditor.meta_stack) for more information.